# Why a change in dependency property of one control (button), do not affect all it's instances?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

This might be a stupid question.

1. Dependency properties are static in nature.
2. Button (which is basically a public class) has somany dependnency properties.

If I use two button in my window, that means different instances of same class...but the static property should be only one. If I change Dependency property of one button change, other should also be changed, right ?

Thanks
Anish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DependencyProperty is not the same as a regular property. It is a property definition that depends on another property to get it's value. It's not meant to contain a value, but instead contains a pointer to another value.

If you do something like `<TextBlock Text="Test" />`, you are pointing the value of the Text DepdencyProperty to a string value which says "Test". If you do `<TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" />`, you are pointing the value to a property on the TextBlock's DataContext (usually a class) called `UserName`.

I actually wrote something [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/07/17/definition-of-a-dependencyproperty/) about how DependencyProperties differ from regular properties if you're interested

Comment: Here the dependency property in .net might be like "TextProperty"...and the corresponding .net wrapper can be "Text" [I think this is the pointer you mentioned before]. But at run time, .net compiler interact directly with the dependency property (not the wrapper)...that means no wrapper properties are created(which are instance properties) at run time. So why dont all button's static property point to same value

Comment: In .Net, the `TextBox.Text` property is a string value. In WPF, the `TextBox.Text` property is a definition of a pointer to a string value. The definition is static, but the value that is being pointed at can be changed.

Comment: So, that means "Text" property is not the .net wrapper, but dependency property ?...By wrapper I mean, the normal .net property which have get/set ...and uses getValue/setValue to get/set dependency property values.

Answer (score 0):

Boiled down to the concept this might help you understand it:

1. Dependency properties are like dictionaries, if `SetValue` is used a new entry with the key of the control and the value you set is created or the value is overwritten. This value can be looked up with `GetValue` later.
2. Only this dictionary is static, the CLR-Wrappers are not, otherwise the object instances could not be added as key.
3. The point of having dependency properties is to not actually have that many fields on ever instance of a control (as you mentioned a Button has quite many properties), that way values can be looked up hierarchically, ultimately going back to a default value defined on the field definition.

Also see of course [the articles on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) for a more correct and in-depth view on the issue.